# Pushing changes to deployed Meteor.js app

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, meteor

After deploying a meteor.js app to my own server, what is the best practice to continue pushing code changes to the live app if I want to develop off the server?

Do you upload the newly edited file to the server via FTP and the page auto-reloads? Doing `meteor bundle app.tgz`, then uploading to server then untarring the package seems to be too slow and inefficient to me.

Comment: how's the live version running? is it a heroku instance? a screen session still using "meteor" (you mention auto-reloads, which makes me think it's later). where's your mongo db being hosted?

Comment: I have not ran the live version yet. Kind of confused how it should be deployed on a Ubuntu server

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to do something that uploads the file, untar it, then restarts the node process.

As soon as it restarts the clients will refresh their pages.

If you find it inefficient and slow you could use a script to do it all for you such as https://github.com/netmute/meteor.sh

You could just edit the parameters in it to match your server.

Comment: If you are developing on your personal system using `meteor`, how will you setup the dev environment to use the live database (not recommended), or a snapshot of the live database. From the dev version of the meteor app, how will you access files located on the live server which are usually accessed using relative paths, and switch back to relative paths after deploying on the live server?